# Slicing Part of a column Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with column 'A' as a string. Within 'A' there are values like
name1-L89783
nametwo-L33009

I would like to make a new column 'B' such that the '-Lxxxx' is removed and all that remains is 'name1' and 'nametwo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['name1-L89783','nametwo-L33009'],columns=['A',])

>>> df
                A
0    name1-L89783
1  nametwo-L33009
```

[`Apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function over rows and put the result in a new column.

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])

>>> df
                A        B
0    name1-L89783    name1
1  nametwo-L33009  nametwo
```

Comment: Awesome! I know this wasn't this original ask, but is there any way to make this work dynamically? Without creating the second column?

Comment: Sure! If I get your meaning you'd just do: `df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])`

Comment: I get this warning: is this going to affect the program at all? If not, how can I suppress it so the user doesn't see it? ------------- A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? The above code is tested to work on 0.17.0 with no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 2):

use vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) for this and then use `str` again to access the array element of interest in this case the first element of the split:

```
In [10]:
df[1] = df[0].str.split('-').str[0]
df

Out[10]:
                0        1
0    name1-L89783    name1
1  nametwo-L33009  nametwo
```

Comment: Like with all good questions, post raw input data, code to reproduce your df, your pandas, python, and numpy versions and the erroneous output

Comment: @EdChum: I don't see how that can work.  Shouldn't it be `.str.split("-").str[0]`?

Comment: @DSM Damn, you're right, I knew I overlooked something, will update